# Modified On Timestamp updated on any changes to a class property

Tags: c#, object, properties

I'm a bit unsure on how I'd word this question, so pardon me if this is duplicate.

Basically I want to call UpdateModifiedTimestamp everytime a property is changed.  This is just a sample class I wrote up pretty quickly, but should explain what I'm trying to achieve.

Everytime Firstname, Lastname, or Phone is changed it should update the ModifiedOn property.

```
public class Student {
   public DateTime ModifiedOn { get; private set; }
   public readonly DateTime CreatedOn;
   public string Firstname { set; get; }
   public string Lastname { set; get; }
   public string Phone { set; get; }

   public Student() {
      this.CreatedOn = DateTime.Now();
   }

   private void UpdateModifiedTimestamp() {
      this.ModifiedOn = DateTime.Now();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are describing sounds pretty close to the property change notification usually done via the [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) interface. Implementing this interface would give you a little more generic solution to your problem:

```
public class Student :INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   public string Firstname { set; get; }
   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

   private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
   {
      UpdateModifiedTimestamp(); // update the timestamp
      if (PropertyChanged != null)
      {
          PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
      }
   }

   string _firstname;
   public string Firstname  //same for other properties
   {
     get
     {
         return _firstname;
     }

     set
     {
        if (value != _firstname)
        {
            _firstname = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Firstname");
        }
     }
   }
 }
```

This approach would make the change notification available to consumers of your class as well, if that's what you are shooting for, a different solution probably would be preferable.

Comment: I think INotifyPropertyChanged makes more sense when the 'listener' is external (for instance a UI control that needs to update itself when the databound source changes). In this case, it's all internal so INotifyPropertyChanged adds more complexity with little added value.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the best way, but one way you could do this is, call the `UpdateModifiedTimeStamp()` method in the three setters of your properties.

eg:

```
public string _firstName;
public string Firstname 
{ 
  get { return this._firstName; }
  set
  {
    this._firstName = value;
    this.UpdateModifiedTimestamp();
  }
}
```

Similarly, do the same for `Lastname`, and `Phone` properties as well.

Comment: This is what I was trying to avoid.  Figured there was a cleaner way of doing this.

Comment: @J. Mitchell: This is the only way I know of besides using INotifyPropertyChanged suggested by @BrokenGlass's answer. I would be interested in know if there is a cleaner way as well.

Comment: @J. Mitchell: As well, not sure about the requirements. But if you are doing this in order to update it to your DataBase, then you should know that usually, people have Triggers on their db tables which would update that columns automatically whenever something gets updated in that table. This will save you time and code instead of hard-coding that logic in your code. Besides, that `ModifiedOn` might not be accurate as you might be calling numerous other methods after updating your `Student` object.

Comment: Just a serialized list kept in memory until a Save() method is called it stores the serialized object (XML) to a DB table.

Comment: @J. Mitchel: Another wacky way of doing it is inheriting from `DynamicObject`, which would allow you to intercept any property access - this comes at huge price though since you lose type safety and are dynamically evaluating property access. Given what you need it's waaaay out there - just mentioning it for completeness.